# Image files scrolling

Tags: bug

In my recent post on the "Avenue of the Gods" I had a problem with the image.

[Did the avenue of the Gods exist?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/25456/the-avenue-of-the-gods-did-it-exist)

If you scroll the page the image changes. Something is wrong.

Comment: It looks like you did something to fix it (used a different image?) I'm not sure what the original issue would have been.

Comment: I eventually used a different image.